# Output capacitor selection for buck transient response

Tags: buck, transient

I am trying to select an output capacitor for an open loop buck converter to meet undershoot and overshoot requirements for a step change in load current.

Below is the equation to find the output capacitor as checked from multiple sources.

[image]

For my buck converter simulation using LTspice, I have L = 100uH, Istep changing from 0 to 2A at t = 10ms, Vin = 12V, Vout = 6V (i.e. 50% duty ratio) and I am trying to meet undershoot of 0.5V.

The above equation gives Co > 133 uF.

I am using 150 uF in my simulation and yet it does not meet the undershoot criteria (Vundershoot is still around 1.5 V instead of 0.5V target.)

Can you please help to understand where I am going wrong? What else do I need to do to meet the target undershoot?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think your equations are for a closed-loop buck.  Even though they may assume that the transient is fast enough that the output cap has to supply most of the current, in an open-loop buck the control loop isn't there to keep the output filter from ringing.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I doubt that too if the above equations are applicable only for closed loop systems. However didn't find the note anywhere that "applicable for closed loop only".

Comment: Simulation is probably your best bet for determining the amount of output capacitance you will need, but don't forget to include parasitics like ESR and ESL.

Comment: Yes, actually this way I can. But was very curious why these equations were not working as they are recommended by multiple reliable sources :)

Comment: Well, the LC resonant frequency is usually well within the control bandwidth of the loop in a closed-loop buck, so you don't see the L-C ringing in that case.  In open-loop operation the transient excites the L-C resonance and you get significant ringing.